# How to arrange data from Firestore in ListView by biggest int values

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I had a Firestore collection named "Users" and Documents of user names , and an integer field of every username , now i wanna compare all those fields and put the biggest one on the top of the list and so on till 10 items , thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the users of your app added as documents within the `Users` collection and the name of the property is `score`, to achieve this, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.collection("Users")
    .orderBy("score", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .limit(10);
```

Comment: This will give the list of users order by descending score (so with the top score first). To then limit to the top 10 only, add `limit(10)` to the end of the query.

Comment: According to Frank's comment, I have updated my answer and added the `limit(10)`. @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank!

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is totally correct but firebase has updated some things and instead of `Query.Direction.DESCENDING`, now it has `descending: true/false` after the comma as a second parameter.

If you want your list to be descending set :

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.collection("Users")
    .orderBy("score", descending : true)
    .limit(10);
```

and vice-versa.